# I install correctly android sdk and all the requirement , but phonegap doesn't work

Tags: android, cordova

Please help me
I want to convert my webapp to android app with phonegap or cordova
but in every step i get error
I am using ubuntu 15.04

This is my sdk manager:

```
Tools:
    Android SDK Tools, Rev: 24.3.3, Status: installed
    Android SDK Build-tools, Rev: 22.0.1, Status: installed
    Android SDK Build-tools, Rev: 19.1, Status: installed
    Android SDK Build-tools, Rev: 17, Status: installed

Tools (Preview Channel):
    Android SDK Platform-tools, Rev: 23 rc3, Status: installed

Android 5.1.1 (API 22)
    SDK Platform, API: 22, Rev: 2, Status: installed
    ARM EABI v7a System Image, API: 22, Rev: 1, Status: installed

Android 4.2.2 (API 17)
    SDK Platform, API: 17, Rev: 2, Status: installed
    ARM EABI v7a System Image, API: 17, Rev: 2, Status: installed

Android 2.1 (API 7)
    SDK Platform, API: 7, Rev: 3, Status: installed
```

but when i run this command:

```
phonegap create first-app
cd first-app
phonegap local build android -d
```

I get this error:

[Error Log](http://paste.ubuntu.ir/nur)

and i want to phonegap use API-7 only
please help to solve this error tnx

Comment: there is sth wrong with your PATH Variable. Echo it and give us the result from it. The Error message is absolutely clear: `What went wrong:

A problem occurred evaluating root project 'android'.

> No installed build tools found. Please install the Android build tools version 19.1.0 or higher.`

Comment: Rather than rely on pastebin could you include the relevant part of the error message in your question

Comment: Sithys my PATH Variable:
PATH=$PATH:~/Public/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools:~/Public/android-sdk-linux/tools

Comment: beresfordt ,, when i copy the error it Identification as spam

Comment: If you do have your path set up correctly, `which android` should spit out the path to the android build tools.

Comment: plz help what i have to do im Hurry

Comment: Check https://developer.android.com/tools/revisions/build-tools.html

Answer (score 0):

i rename the 19.1.0 build-tools only to 19.1.0 and problem solved
now i get this error

> - What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':processDebugManifest'.
>
>   > Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 7 cannot be smaller than version 10 declared in library
>   >     /home/arvinall/Public/cordovaP/first-app/platforms/android/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/android/CordovaLib/unspecified/debug/AndroidManifest.xml
>
>   Suggestion: use tools:overrideLibrary="org.apache.cordova" to force
>     usage